# How to apply H*p + t homography in matlab

Tags: matlab

---

I'm working on a project in computer vision in MATLAB and I have to apply a special homography that looks like that : H1*(H2*p + t1).

H1, H2 - 3x3 matrix

T1 - 3x1 vector

p - is the image homogeneous coordinates of an image (3x1 vector)

Regular homography looks like H*p. I know how to apply those homographis but all the functions in MATLAB that I have found wont work on this special case.
If someone knows how to do it I'll be very happy to read it. Thanks.

Comment: 1.) Why the c++ tag? 2.) What troubles in MATLAB do have, exactly? If you have all the matrices and vectors, multiplying them shouldn't be an issue, but maybe I am missing your point.

Answer (score 0):

If `t1` is planar translation, that is `tx, ty` (scalars), then you can define the translation matrix `T`:

```
 >> T = eye(3);
 >> T(1:2,3) = [tx;ty];
```

Now all you have to do is combine the operators into a single homography (note the order):

```
 >> H = H1 * T * H2;
```